# Ajax Call: Problem with filter in Article & Articles Model in Module Context

Tags: module, articles, ajax

I currently have a problem with an ajax call in my new module. the filters are not used. Here is an extract of the relevant lines:

```
$articleid    = $data_decoded->articleid;

// Get an instance of the generic articles model
require_once(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_content/models/articles.php');
$model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Articles', 'ContentModel', array('ignore_request' => true));

$model->setState('filter.article_id', $articleid);

return $model->getItems();
```

$articleid contains the searched article ID as an integer.

The function returns the complete list of existing articles.

The goal is to receive the searched article and / but filter also to check for access restrictions & published state...

Added:
If i am using the Article Model like used below, i can also not filter is that correct? (it returns an empty article object)

```
require_once(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_content/models/article.php');
$model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Article', 'ContentModel', array('ignore_request' => true));

    $model->setState('filter.article_id', 22);

    return $model->getItem();
```

I'm sure it's just a stupid mistake or i misunderstood something, but I just don't see...

Thanks for your feedback

Comment: Are you using administrator models intentionally?

Comment: i am not sure what i can or should use, in the end it should display the articles in the frontend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Administrator side's `ContentModelArticles` does not support filtering by ID.

`ContentModelArticle` does support it. The state property name is `article.id`:

```
$model->setState('article.id', $articleId);
```

If this is a frontend module you might want to use the frontend articles model:

```
// Register frontend model classes.
JModelLegacy::addIncludePath(JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_content/models', 'ContentModel');

// Get the articles model.
$model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Articles', 'ContentModel', ['ignore_request' => true]);

// Set up dummy params to prevent errors.
$model->setState('params', new JRegistry);

// Filter by article IDs.
$model->setState('filter.article_id', $articleIds);

// Get the articles.
$articles = $model->getItems();
```